# Django Cryptographic "signing.loads(value)" giving None with same SECRET_KEY

Tags: django, cryptography, signing

I have 2 Django Project with same `SECRET_KEY`.

Using First project we are encrypting some important data using `'signing.dumps(value)'` and sending via rest to another django project.

Now I am trying to decrypt using `signing.loads(value)` its giving None why?